# Which should be the first responder: my view or UIDatePicker?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uidatepicker, first-responder

I'm creating sibling of `UITextField`, but with `UIDatePicker` instead of a keyboard.

I want multiple such controls to play nicely with each other and also standard `UITextField` (i.e. swap keyboard for date picker when my control is activated, and hide date picker when a text field is activated).

One thing that confuses me is handling of first responder status. `UIDatePicker` doesn't seem to ask to become the first responder. Should it? Can I rely on it not becoming first responder and hide date picker when my own control is asked to resign first responder?

Should I set `UIDatePicker` (or anything else) as my control's `nextResponder`? I don't want to handle any events, I just want to make sure that my control steals and resigns focus when necessary.

*(I'm not using nibs in this case)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the resignFirstResponder method in your class, write your hide-UIDatePicker code in it, after checking the instance is the category of your sibling class.